# Explicit types from interfaces using DataContractSerializer

Tags: xml, wpf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am writing an XML using a DataContractSerializer in WPF. I need the XML to be as clean as possible (there is no requirement that is needs to be deserialised back into the same application), without any namespaces etc.
This mostly works, but I am having an issue with my Arrays/Lists/IEnumerables when they are of an interfaced type.

As minimal working example, I want to serialise the following data structure:

```
namespace HR
{
    public interface IEmployee
    { 
        string FirstName { get; }
        string LastName { get; }
    }


    [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    [KnownType(typeof(Employee))]
    public class Employee : IEmployee
    {
        public Employee(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Business
{
    [DataContract(Namespace ="")]
    public class Company
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public IEmployee CEO { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public IEnumerable<IEmployee> Employees;
    }
}
```

The way I'm serialising this is the following:

```
namespace Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee jimApple = new Employee("Jim", "Apple");
        Employee bob = new Employee("Bob", "the Builder");
        Company company = new Company
        {
            CEO = jimApple,
            Employees = new List<Employee> { jimApple, bob }
        };

        var outputPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Test.xml");
        Stream outputStream = new System.IO.FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create);
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Company));
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, company);
        }
    }
}
```

What this writes out as is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CEO xmlns="" i:type="Employee">
    <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
    <LastName>Apple</LastName>
  </CEO>
  <CompanyName i:nil="true" />
  <Employees xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:anyType xmlns="" i:type="Employee">
      <FirstName>Jim</FirstName>
      <LastName>Apple</LastName>
    </d2p1:anyType>
    <d2p1:anyType xmlns="" i:type="Employee">
      <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
      <LastName>the Builder</LastName>
    </d2p1:anyType>
  </Employees>
</Company>
```

Now this is nearly good, but I need the line `<d2p1:anyType xmlns="" i:type="Employee">` to simply look like `<Employee>`. Also I prefer to get rid of the `xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"`.

I have been looking into DataContractResolver class to do this kind of thing, but with no luck. Any way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a custom collection type and decorate it with the `CollectionDataContract` attribute:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Company
{
    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public IEmployee CEO { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public EmployeeCollecion Employees;
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Employee", Namespace = "")]
public class EmployeeCollecion : List<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeCollecion() : base() { }

    public EmployeeCollecion(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }

    public EmployeeCollecion(IEnumerable<Employee> collection) : base(collection) { }
}
```

This is probably how far you get using the `DataContractResolver`. If you require custom serialization and "there is no requirement that is needs to be deserialised back into the same application", it seems easier to do the serialization yourself.

Comment: It works so that's definitely something, but I'm slightly sad it requires changing the data structure to achieve it

Comment: @Yellow: Well, like I said, if you want maximum flexibility, you're probably better off writing your own custom serializer.